# why can't I update my values with a simple statement?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-update

I'm trying to update some values in my table, but I haven't seem this error before, why a trigger is interfering with the Query? How could I update the values then?

The trigger that is interfering is AFTER UPDATE trigger, and it has nothing to do with the field "COUNTRY"

```
UPDATE RM00102
SET COUNTRY = 'United States'
where COUNTRY = 'USA'
```

**ERROR**

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure LC_CustHoldStatus, Line 25 [Batch Start Line 18]
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>   The statement has been terminated.*

Comment: That query, and that error, are not related. There is no subquery in that SQL. If you have a trigger, you should be posting it's DDL too.

Comment: The trigger is probably written to handle one-row updates only. It needs to be corrected. Show us the trigger code.

Comment: BTW, tables have _columns_. not fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
AFTER UPDATE

AS



declare @StatusOld as tinyint
declare @StatusNew as Tinyint
declare @CustomerRemoved as nchar(400)
declare @CUstomer nchar(32)
declare @HoldReason as nchar(400)
declare @CustomerHold as nchar(400)


select @StatusOld = hold from Deleted
select @StatusNew = hold from Inserted
select @CustomerRemoved = 'A HOLD was removed for '+rtrim(Custnmbr)+'-'+rtrim(Custname) from inserted
select @customer = (select custnmbr from inserted)
select @HOldReason = (select coalesce([hold status],'') from VWCUSTINFO where [Customer Number]=@CUstomer)

select @CustomerHOld = 'This customer '+rtrim(Custnmbr)+'-'+rtrim(Custname)+' was recently placed on HOLD due to '+@HoldReason from inserted
```

the trigger is placed in another table, I know it is a newbie mistake

Comment: `inserted` and `deleted` are tables so that they can represent the results of set operations. Designing a trigger on the assumption that it will always process exactly one row is generally a bad plan. If you are absolutely certain there will never be more than one row then _please_ add a check for the number of rows and use `RaIsError` or `Throw` to explicitly inform those who come along later that they have attempted to execute an unacceptable statement. (`if ( select Count(*) from inserted ) > 1 RaIsError( 'FooTable_Insert: No more than one row may be processed.', 25, 42 ) with log`)

Comment: I will try that. Thanks HABO